# How can i hide and display (animation) of UIView as UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new at iOS development, So please attention at My Question.

As my title said,

How Can i hide and display `UIView` (*with Animation*) as `UIActionSheet` ?
Searched in google, bud didn't find a valid solution..

**NOTE :** [i found following line but its not help me.](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/andrew_homeyer/display_a_custom_uiview_like_a.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following code:

```
- (IBAction)showTapped:(id)sender {
    hideButton.enabled=YES;
    showButton.enabled=NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        subView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 225, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}

- (IBAction)hideTapped:(id)sender {
    hideButton.enabled=NO;
    showButton.enabled=YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        subView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 480, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks dude your answer is help me :) its simple, short and correct answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Well in this case what you can do is add a `UIView` on the window and then show it when you want to. So, firstly what you will have to do is create an object of `AppDelegate`.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

And create your view like

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 300);
 UIView *ActionView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
```

This is to show your view on the window, note the **y coordinate** of your view should be below the dimensions of the screen so that you can bring it back up to a certain level and then send it down again.

```
[appDelegate.window addSubview:ActionView];
```

Then simply add these custom animations to show and hide your view

To Reveal your View

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
CGRect rect = [ActionView frame];
rect.origin.y = -300;
[ActionView setFrame:rect];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

To Hide your View

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
CGRect rect = [ScrollView frame];
rect.origin.y = 460;
[ScrollView setFrame:rect];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Lastly you can adjust to your own dimensions and frames. Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks dude you answer is absolutely correct but may be shukhpal's answer is very simple then you :) +1 vote from me :)

Comment: btw he gave u the direct code ... theres no mention of the view being used as an actionsheet

Comment: from iOS4+ the Apple strongly recommends the block-based animation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.... it works

```
#pragma mark - Date Selector View PresentModelView with Transparent ViewController

- (void) showModal:(UIView*) modalView {

    UIWindow *mainWindow = [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window];

    CGPoint middleCenter;


    middleCenter = CGPointMake(modalView.center.x, modalView.center.y);

    CGSize offSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

    CGPoint offScreenCenter = CGPointMake(offSize.width / 2.0, offSize.height * 1.5);
    modalView.center = offScreenCenter;

    if ([[mainWindow subviews] containsObject:modalView]) {
        [modalView removeFromSuperview];
    }


    [mainWindow addSubview:modalView];

    [mainWindow bringSubviewToFront:modalView];
    // Show it with a transition effect
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    // animation duration in seconds
    modalView.center = middleCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

// Use this to slide the semi-modal view back down.
- (void) hideModal:(UIView*) modalView {

    CGSize offSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    CGPoint offScreenCenter = CGPointMake(offSize.width / 2.0, offSize.height * 1.5);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void *)(modalView)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(hideModalEnded:finished:context:)];
    modalView.center = offScreenCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void) hideModalEnded:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    UIView *modalView = (__bridge UIView *)context;
    [modalView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this, follow the below steps:-

1) Drag `UIView` named as pickerView, add inside your view.

2) Drag `UIToolBar` (if needed), add inside your view.

3) Drag `UIPickerView`, add inside your view.

4) Connect the `IBOutlet` to pickerView.

5) Now implement the below methods inside your code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height+300, self.view.frame.size.width, 300);
}

-(void)hidePickerView{
    self.isPickerHidden = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height+300, self.view.frame.size.width, 300);
    }];
}

-(void)showPickerView{
    self.isPickerHidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        self.pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-300, self.view.frame.size.width, 300);
    }];
}

//Assuming you are tapping on cell, or you can use button connecting to the IBAction as well  
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (self.isPickerHidden){
      [self showPickerView];
    }
    else{
        [self hidePickerView];
    }
}
```